# Save data from API to laravel DB

Tags: laravel, database

I was wondering how I can fetch data from a open API like jsonplaceholder and then save it to my database for future needs?

I already built my model and migration, but how can I make sure I use it after fetching data? And what would be the best way to do it? Essentially I just want someone to fetch the data, make a migration and then be able to use that data from their database.

Currently, I just have a route which fetches the data but doesn't store it anywhere.

```
        $data = Http::get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums')->json(); 
        return view('welcome', ['data' => $data]);
        
    }
```

My current very simple model:

```
class Albums extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $table="albums";
    public $id="id";
    public $title="title";
    

}
```

Any pointers or help I'm very grateful for!

Comment: what was the response data of open API? what happen when error on open API response?

Comment: @BhargavChudasama The whole fetching of data works fine, theres no errors. But it just routes me to a view of $data so i can use it there.

What im wondering is, how would i proceed to save that data to my database?

Comment: share response data of open API

Comment: @BhargavChudasama Here is a picture of the data: https://gyazo.com/04c56e538657b7a41cb6e8996e536de9